# Android studio emulator network bridge is not worked

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, react-native

I'd like to start developing with `react-native`. I install android studio 2.3.3 with emulator. My host machine is Windows 7 Phenom 965. I create Nexus 5X API24 Android 7 arm (also tried Nexus 6 arm64).

The build system of react-native start program in android which can not download package from packager due to network unreacheble. 
I read about networking in android [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html) and inspect networking from `adb shell`

```js
generic:/ $ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:UNSPEC
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope: Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:248 TX bytes:248

eth0      Link encap:UNSPEC
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456/64 Scope: Link
          inet6 addr: fec0::5054:ff:fe12:3456/64 Scope: Site
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:110 TX bytes:316

generic:/ $ ping 10.0.2.15
PING 10.0.2.15 (10.0.2.15) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.2.15: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=10.8 ms
^C
--- 10.0.2.15 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 31ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.829/10.829/10.829/0.000 ms
generic:/ $ ping 10.0.2.2
connect: Network is unreachable
generic:/ $ ping 10.0.2.1
connect: Network is unreachable
generic:/ $ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Disabling Windows firewall does not solve the problem. Also no any firewall question dialog is appears.

Any help very appreciated.